# Python : generator object when iterating list

Tags: python

I am getting generator object when iterating over a list and appending to other list.

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b=[6,7,8,9]
>>> c=None
>>> c=(i for i in a)
>>> c
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1070baaa0>
>>> c.append(i for i in b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How to adding values from one list to another existing list?

Comment: `c` is a generator, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: If you want to get a `list` instead of a generator, replace the parentheses with square brackets.

Comment: If you want a copy of a do `c = a[:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the generator expression in square brackets to turn it into a list:

```
c=[i for i in a]
```

That said, this is a redundant generator when you could just use

```
c = a + b
```

since you're not changing or evaluating any of the elements in the list and concatenation creates a new list.

Comment: why all the downvotes? sure `c=a[:]` is smarter but this is the OP's generator expression as a list expression

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I think the initial answer had a generator expression wrapped in a list!

Comment: @JoranBeasley It did! It was a pretty foolish typo, considering.

Comment: The concatenation already creates a new list object, the slice copy is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems: **A)** you are mixing up generators with lists and **B)** you want to use the list method `extend()` instead of `append()`.

## A) Lists vs Generators

When you write: `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]` you are creating a list and referring to it as `a`.

When you write:`c = (i for i in a)` you are creating a generator and referring to it as `c`.

If you would like to append `a` to `c` you will first have to convert `c` to a list.  This can be done a couple of ways:

1. Make it a list from the start:
   `c = [i for i in a]` will return a list with all the elements in `a`.  This is called a list comprehension.
2. Convert the generator into a list:

   ```
   c = (i for i in a)
   c = list(c)
   ```

Now that `c` is a list, you can append `b` to it:

`c.append(b)
[1, 2, 3, 4, [6, 7, 8, 9]]`

uh oh, look out!  Append adds another element to the end of a list and that element can be another list.  In this case the 5th element of `c` is another list.

## B) Using `extend()` instead of `append()`

What you really want is to use the extend method of a list.  This method appends all the elements in an iterable to the iterable that called the method.

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9]
c.extend(b)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[====c=====] [====b====]
```

Also, if all you want is to create a new list with elements of two previous lists you can do the following:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
list3 = list1 + list2
```

OR

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
list3 = [i for i in list1] + [j for j in list2]
```

to practice your list comprehensions